# Can not benefit from asp.net MVC Data Annotations & Html helpers when using dataTable jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I am working on the following :-

- asp.net mvc5 web application.
- dataTable jQuery plugins version 1.10.4

but i have noted that i can not benefit from these asp.net mvc features , if i use the dataTable plugin:-

- I can not use html helpers.
- The data annotation applied will have no effect.

For example I have the following Script to implement the dataTable plugin:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": "Home/AjaxHandler",
                "processing": true,
                "columns": [
                            { "data": "FName" },
                            { "data": "LName" },
                            { "data": "BDate" }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And the following action method:-

```
 public ActionResult AjaxHandler(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
            {
                var allCompanies = t.Emps;

                var result = allCompanies.Select(c=> new {c.FName, c.LName, c.BDate});
                           //  select new[] {  };

                return Json(new
                {
                    sEcho = param.sEcho,
                    iTotalRecords = allCompanies.Count(),
                    iTotalDisplayRecords = allCompanies.Count(),
                    aaData = result
                },
                                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

And the following view:-

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}





<table id="myDataTable" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>FName</th>
            <th>LName</th>
            <th>BDate</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

And the following model:-

```
namespace testplugins.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class Emp
    {
        public int EmpID { get; set; }
       [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DeptID { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> BDate { get; set; }

        public virtual Dept Dept { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now for example I can not use `Html.DisplayNameFor(a=>a.FName)` and get the name as defined inside the data annotation. and instead of that i need to manually write the html table headers labels.

Also for the Bdate the value inside the dataTable will be displayed as “/Date(315536524000)/” so I even can not benefit from `DataType.Date` data annotation, also if I am going to edit the records using the dataTable plugin then data annotation such as Required, stringlenght will also have no effect.

So can anyone advice on this please? and can i modify the dataTable plugin to be more asp.net mvc oriented ? or i am doing things wrongly in my above code ?

Comment: you can follow the approach shown [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part)

Comment: @Aminul i already read this link and it basically caused me to write this question, after i test it. because as you see from the example there is no way to use html helpers or benefit from the data annotations...

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could accomplish this...

This is just creating a little template string, putting it into a JS variable, and using the render function to output that string with the data inside the value attribute.

Razor:

```
@model testplugins.Models.Emp


<table id="myDataTable" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>FName</th>
            <th>LName</th>
            <th>BDate</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    var fnameTextBox = '@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FName)';
</script>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "Home/AjaxHandler",
            "processing": true,
            "columns": [
                    { "data": "FName" },
                    { "data": "LName" },
                    { "data": "BDate" }
            ],
            "render": function( data, type, row, meta ){
                 return fnameTextBox.replace('value=""', 'value="' + data + '"');
            }
         });
    });
</script>
```